# Using a variable in enzyme wrapper find method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

Clunking through learning testing with jest + enzyme. I have an array, `OptionsArray`, with some options that get mapped to buttons in a component. I figured that in the testing suite for the component, I could just do

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { OptionsArray } from './ConfigOptions';
import Foo from './Foo';

describe('Foo', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    const numberOfOptions = OptionsArray.length;

    beforeEach(() => (wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)));

    it('renders exactly one Button Item for each option', () => {
        /* eslint-disable-next-line testing-library/no-debugging-utils */
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        OptionsArray.forEach((option) => {
            console.log(option.value);
        });
        OptionsArray.forEach((option) => {
            expect(wrapper.find(option.value)).toHaveLength(1);
        });
    });
});
```

I see the options fine in the console output, but then I get:

```
Foo › renders exactly one Button Item for each option

expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
```

So I'm guessing that I'm passing the variable to `find` incorrectly? Is there a better way to do this?

**Adding component Foo:**

```
/* Foo.tsx */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { OptionsArray } from './ConfigOptions';
import './Foo.scss';

const Foo: React.FC<> = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(OptionsArray);

    return (
        <div className="Foo">
            <ListGroup>
                {OptionsArray.map((option, i) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={i}>
                        <Button
                            id={i.toString()}
                            value={option.value}
                            onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.currentTarget.id)}
                            variant={option.isSet ? 'primary' : 'outline-primary'}
                        >
                            {option.value}
                        </Button>
                        {option.content}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Foo;
```

And the `OptionsArray`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const OptionsArray = [
    {
        value: 'OptionA',
        content: (
            <React.Fragment>
                <br />
                <p>Here is a description of OptionA.</p>
            </React.Fragment>
        ),
        isSet: false,
    },
    {
        value: 'OptionB',
        content: (
            <React.Fragment>
                <br />
                <p>Here is a description of OptionB.</p>
            </React.Fragment>
        ),
        isSet: false,
    },
];
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the component so that we know what you want to test

Comment: @slideshowp2 Yep, added!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As usual, just a misunderstanding on my part. I was trying to use `find` to get the `Button` components by text, but this [isn't how `find` works](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html). Instead, I needed to use [the `findWhere` method](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/findWhere.html) and a predicate to hunt down the exact components I was looking for. Here was my solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { OptionsArray } from './ConfigOptions';
import Foo from './Foo';

describe('Foo', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    const numberOfOptions = OptionsArray.length;

    beforeEach(() => (wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)));

    it('renders exactly one Button Item for each option', () => {
        OptionsArray.forEach((option) => {
            expect(wrapper.find({ value: option.value })).toHaveLength(1);
            const ButtonWithText = wrapper.findWhere((node) => {
                return node.name() === 'Button' && node.text() === option.value;
            });
            expect(ButtonWithText ).toHaveLength(1);
        });
    });
});
```